# Page goes to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insval()
{

    var insno=document.getElementById('ins').value;
    var a=1;
    for(k=1;k<=insno;k++)
    {
        if((document.getElementById('num_cat'+k).value=="")||(document.getElementById('num_cat'+k).value=="0"))
        {

            alert("Please Select Number of Insulins");
            a=2;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var num = $('#num_cat'+ k).val();

            var i;
            for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
            {
                if(document.getElementById('insulin'+k+i).value=="")
                {
                    alert("Please Insert Insulins");
                    a=2;
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }

        if(a==2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if((k+1)==insno)
        {
            tabval();
        }
    }

    function tabval()
    {
        var tabno=document.getElementById('tabletno').value;

        for(k=1;k<=tabno;k++)
        {
            if((document.getElementById('tab_cat'+k).value=="")||(document.getElementById('tab_cat'+k).value=="0"))
            {
                alert("Please Select Number of Tablets");
                a=2;
                return false;
            } 
            else
            {
                var num = $('#tab_cat'+ k).val();
                var i;
                for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
                {
                    if(document.getElementById('tablet'+k + i).value==""||document.getElementById('tablet'+k + i).value=="0")
                    {
                        alert("Please Insert Tablets");
                        a=2;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

I'm creating a php page and i used the above code for validation of my form.When i submit my
form the page goes for infinite loop and it won't stop or refresh or take the query to insert data into database.
thank you

Comment: i want to check if the value of insno=2 and tabno=0

Comment: You have a for loop (k = 1; k <= insno; k++) without declaring k as local variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the input value as

```
    var insno=document.getElementById('ins').value;
```

the returned value is a string in javascript

so, you will have to explicitly convert it to a number using

```
    var insno=parseInt(document.getElementById('ins').value,10);
```

also scope the "k" variable in your for loop.
In the nested function tabval, the value of "k" is again reset to 1, so the for loop (insval) starts again from k=1.

That should solve the infinite loop problem.

Comment: is it possible to call tabval() inside insval().

Comment: you can call tabval inside insval, but I noticed that you have not correctly scoped the "k" variable

insval has a 

        for(k=1;k<=insno;k++){...}

and tabval also has a 

        for(k=1;k<=tabno;k++)

as a result, everytime tabval is called, the value of k is set to 1, so the loop continues infinitely.

instead use different variable names
or scope them as shown below:

        for(var k=1;k<=insno;k++)

and

        for(var k=1;k<=tabno;k++)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare numbers with numbers instead of a number with a string, like you do inside your loop. The solution is quite easy :

```
for(var k=1;k<=parseInt(insno,10);k++)
```

Or even more better would be :

```
var insno= parseInt(document.getElementById('ins').value,10);
```

Comment: 'insno' is a number and i'm able to print it.

Comment: But when you say: 
    var insno=document.getElementById('ins').value;
then insno will be a text like "2" and not the number 2. That is why you need to add parseInt(...) like I described above

Comment: also i changed var tabno=parseInt(document.getElementById('tabletno').value,10);

Comment: it will work if the tabval() function is removed. I think some thing wrong with the tabval() function.

Comment: you need to change the variable "num" to an integer too: var num = parseInt($('#tab_cat'+ k).val(),10); Same with the variable "tabno"